# Maven project plugin error,When I click on project the maven project it show's error as below

Tags: maven

I am having this error "An error has occurred. See error log for more details. Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.archetype.ArchetypePlugin.getActiveArchetypeCatalogs()" because "archetype Manager" is null" since I add the remote catalog I was learning cucumber could you please help me to fix this error. I can not create anymore Maven project!! thanks!
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7OjW.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0c2hR.png)

I was trying to find this remote-catalog to delete from M2 after some search but I cannot find it yet, please I am preparing for interviews I need your help as soon as possible, Thanks!